# How to extract all (finite) possible strings from regex?

Tags: regex, pcre

Is there any tool to output any possible strings that matches a regex?

Actually, there are lots of tools to convert example texts to regex. I want to do the opposite when the possible strings are finite.

Also, is it possible to convert a regex to a set of regexs that each of them only matches a fixed length pattern?

Example: `reg1= [A-Za-z][aeio]?[A-Za-z]` can be converted to `reg2= [A-Za-z][aeio][A-Za-z]` and `reg3= [A-Za-z][A-Za-z]`. `reg1` matches 2-3 length strings but `reg2` only matches 2 and `reg3` only matches 3-length strings.

Comment: _“Is there any tool to output any possible strings that matches a regex?”_ – that would be an endless list for a regular expression such as `.*`

Comment: I know. I mean the cases that possible strings are known to be a finite set.

Answer (score 1):

It's not always possible to generate **all** valid solutions from a regex, and I don't think you'll be able to find a tool to do it, as it a niche use (even for a finite set).

It's possible to build something to generate the whole (finite) set of solutions. But it would never be able to cover all PCRE specification, and we would be forced to makes choices:

- don't care about dot (`.`)
- don't care about negative character classes (`\W`, `\D`...)
- don't care about undefined quantifiers (`*`, `+`)
- ...

So many restrictions that the time required to build a good tool doesn't worth it.

Anyway, you may find [Xeger](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xeger) interesting, as this library generate random valid strings, based on a regex (PCRE).

Comment: There is no problem with (.) as it may match any ONE symbol. Also, (\W,\w,\D,...) are okay as they do not affect the length of the accepted string. e.g. \w can be written as [+-.,!@#$%^&*();\/|<>"'] which is only one character. But, you are right about (*,+,?) which affect the length.

Comment: I agree dot (`.`) match one symbol, but the amount of available symbols evolve in time. If you're using UTF-8, it can represent more than 16 millions different symbols. The simple expression `/^...$/` (which has a defined length: 3) has **4722 billions of billions** valid solutions, supposing you're not using 5-bytes characters.

Comment: I agree. So please consider my second question. /^...$/ is okay but I want to convert /^..?.$/ to /^...$/ and /^..$/. I mean a set of regexs which result in fixed length strings.